# AutoRenewable Subscription Related Query [Server-User Mapping]

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

I am implementing a digital magazine project for a client. Auto-renewable subscriptions for a period of 3/6/12 months have been included as a feature. My question is while using in-app purchase, is there any way for the server to map the user?? Anyway to identify a particular user is using it? I have done extensive research and know that apple doesn't allow the user's apple-id to be mapped?? Is there any other way to identify a particular user?

The problem arises for subscription. If an user has undertaken a subscription for let's say 3 months, then my app has to show DOWNLOAD button for all the 3 months instead of the regular BUY button. But when a new magazine is launched on to the storefront, how would the app know that this person is subscribed or not and convert the BUY to DOWNLOAD?

Answer (score 1):

When a user buys a subscription, you should store the receipt on your server.  This receipt, in a way, becomes your way to identify the user's account.  Whenever you want to check the status of an account, send that receipt to iTunes for verification and it'll respond with the latest receipt for that subscription, along with the expiration date.  Since you've made a note of which specific device that receipt came from, you can provide the proper UI to that user.

Now, if the user installs your app on a new device they can tap a `Restore` button that you've provided in your app. That button will call `restoreCompletedTransactions` which will send all the Auto-Renewing receipts for that user's Apple ID to the device.